# Swift3 Microphone Audio Input - play without record

Tags: ios, swift3, avfoundation

I am trying to play microphone audio input using swift3 without recording. I can record the audio with the following code:

```
let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    try! session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker)

    try! audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(url: filePath!, settings: [:])
    audioRecorder.delegate = self
    audioRecorder.isMeteringEnabled = true
    audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
    audioRecorder.record()
```

and then play it back ultimately after picking up the recorded file with:

```
audioPlayerNode.play()
```

But I would like to skip the recording step and play directly from the microphone input to the audio out (in this case the player node).  It then functions like an actual microphone. Can I do this directly or does an interim file need to exist? I combed the AVFoundation documentation but I can't seem to get a handle on the direct route. Any ideas or suggestions are appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `AVAudioEngine`, although you will hear feedback:

```
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let engine = AVAudioEngine()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let input = engine.inputNode!
        let player = AVAudioPlayerNode()
        engine.attach(player)

        let bus = 0
        let inputFormat = input.inputFormat(forBus: bus)
        engine.connect(player, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: inputFormat)

        input.installTap(onBus: bus, bufferSize: 512, format: inputFormat) { (buffer, time) -> Void in
            player.scheduleBuffer(buffer)
        }

        try! engine.start()
        player.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, works well but the service is difficult to stop without causing a crash.  Do I need to do anything with the node after the engine is stopped in order to have a workable restart? thx

Comment: How are you stopping and starting and what sort of crash do you get?

Comment: Actually, I got it.  I had an error in my stop function.  Thanks again for this!!