# Play audio on iOS from a memory data stream

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation

I am porting an audio library to iOS allowing to play audio streams fed from callbacks. The user provides a callback returning raw PCM data, and I need to have this data be played. Moreover, the library must be able to play multiple streams at once.

I figured I would need to use AVFoundation, but it seems like AVAudioPlayer does not support streamed audio buffers, and all the streaming documentation I could find used data coming directly from the network. What is the API I should use here?

Thanks in advance!

By the way, I am not using the Apple libraries through Swift or Objective-C. However I assume everything is exposed still, so an example in Swift would be greatly appreciated anyway!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: `AVAudioEngine` + `AVAudioPlayerNode` let's you play audio from buffers. Here's an example that uses a single player, with audio buffers taken from the microphone: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43670810/22147

Comment: Thank you to all of you, Audio Queues are exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialise:

1. The Audio Session to use input audio unit and output.

   ```
   -(SInt32) audioSessionInitialization:(SInt32)preferred_sample_rate {

       // - - - - - - Audio Session initialization
       NSError *audioSessionError = nil;
       session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

       // disable AVAudioSession
       [session setActive:NO error:&audioSessionError];

       // set category - (PlayAndRecord to use input and output session AudioUnits)
      [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker error:&audioSessionError];

      double preferredSampleRate = 441000;
      [session setPreferredSampleRate:preferredSampleRate error:&audioSessionError];

      // enable AVAudioSession
      [session setActive:YES error:&audioSessionError];


      // Configure notification for device output change (speakers/headphones)
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                        selector:@selector(routeChange:)
                                            name:AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification
                                          object:nil];


      // - - - - - - Create audio engine
      [self audioEngineInitialization];

      return [session sampleRate];
    }
   ```
2. The Audio Engine

   ```
   -(void) audioEngineInitialization{

       engine = [[AVAudioEngine alloc] init];
       inputNode = [engine inputNode];
       outputNode = [engine outputNode];

       [engine connect:inputNode to:outputNode format:[inputNode inputFormatForBus:0]];


       AudioStreamBasicDescription asbd_player;
       asbd_player.mSampleRate        = session.sampleRate;
       asbd_player.mFormatID            = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
       asbd_player.mFormatFlags        = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
       asbd_player.mFramesPerPacket    = 1;
       asbd_player.mChannelsPerFrame    = 2;
       asbd_player.mBitsPerChannel    = 16;
       asbd_player.mBytesPerPacket    = 4;
       asbd_player.mBytesPerFrame        = 4;

       OSStatus status;
       status = AudioUnitSetProperty(inputNode.audioUnit,
                                 kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                                 kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                                 0,
                                 &asbd_player,
                                 sizeof(asbd_player));


       // Add the render callback for the ioUnit: for playing
       AURenderCallbackStruct callbackStruct;
       callbackStruct.inputProc = engineInputCallback; ///CALLBACK///
       callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = (__bridge void *)(self);
       status = AudioUnitSetProperty(inputNode.audioUnit,
                                 kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback,
                                 kAudioUnitScope_Input,//Global
                                 kOutputBus,
                                 &callbackStruct,
                                 sizeof(callbackStruct));

       [engine prepare];
   }
   ```
3. The Audio Engine callback

   ```
   static OSStatus engineInputCallback(void *inRefCon,
                                AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                                const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp,
                                UInt32 inBusNumber,
                                UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                                AudioBufferList *ioData)
   {

       // the reference to the audio controller where you get the stream data
       MyAudioController *ac = (__bridge MyAudioController *)(inRefCon);

       // in practice we will only ever have 1 buffer, since audio format is mono
       for (int i = 0; i < ioData->mNumberBuffers; i++) { 
           AudioBuffer buffer = ioData->mBuffers[i];

           // copy stream buffer data to output buffer
           UInt32 size = min(buffer.mDataByteSize, ac.playbackBuffer.mDataByteSize); 
           memcpy(buffer.mData, ac.streamBuffer.mData, size);
           buffer.mDataByteSize = size; // indicate how much data we wrote in the buffer
       }

       return noErr;
   }
   ```